# Android, Managing many objects that have bitmaps as properties

Tags: java, android

I was just wondering what the best approach is for this in a mobile setting.

I have a list of say `100 Objects`. Each of these objects with have a `photo` attached, which I will be loading as a `bitmap`. So my first instinct was to create a `Bitmap` property, and when the objects are instantiated, I load the `bitmap` property for each of the `100 Objects`.

As I figured this is not a very good approach, because as I try to load a `listview` of these objects with a `picture` and a `title`. My app jumps from `14mb` memory allocated to `75mb`. And on some lower end devices it crashes immediately.

I was just wondering what are considered some of the best practices for situations like this.

Another thing I was thinking of doing is to have a method for the object, which will load the `bitmap` when needed, based on the `filename string` for each of the objects. Thoughts?

EDIT:
The problem is the memory allocation is jumping to high once I add the bitmaps to the objects, I need a better way to hold references to the images within the objects. The images are not even being displayed yet.

Comment: Have you try `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @Stanojkovic Well the problem I am talking about is different, the memory allocation is too high before the image is even loaded into view. I am trying to figure out the best way to hold references to the bitmaps in the objects themselves.

Comment: And the listview rows will be reused and recycled, so there won't be a problem once I get to that part.

Comment: @BobbyW Maybe try to hold only their path on a `String`?

Comment: @giannisf Yeah thats what I mentioned in the post, I was just looking for feedback if that was the way to go, or maybe there is an even better implementation I don't know about.

Comment: Have you read this articles: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html and this:http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Hold the path to bitmap file in your model, and in the `adapter` get the actual `Bitmap`.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to hold that many bitmaps in memory. You could use a `LruCache` to make sure the app doesn't crash but that is a solution only to speed up the retrieval of the most recent ones, not to keep them all in memory.

It is best to keep a reference to the bitmap sources instead and load the actual bitmaps as needed, depending on your use case. For example, if you want to list them, use a `RecyclerView` together with a library such as `Picasso`. This way you let these components better handle the memory for you.